How many vertices can be in a graph if degree of each vertex is 7?
How many vertices can be in a graph if degree of each vertex is 7?
let N be the amount of vertices.
The only thing that comes to my mind is handshaking lemma, so we know that N is even. What else can we do here?

There are two simple conditions that immediately occur to me - the first is that there must be at least $8$ nodes. The other is there must be an even number, which you already got.

Can you find examples with $8$, $10$, $12$, $14$ vertices?

If there is an answer for $N,M$ the disjoint union of the two gives an answer for $N+M,$ unless you require connected, but there is an easy way to work around that if so.

There are easy examples for $N=8$ and $N=14,$ From this you get every even number $\geq 36.$

If $N \ge 8$ is even, then try the graph whose vertices are the elements of $\mathbb{Z} / N\mathbb{Z}$, and where there is an edge between $a$ and $b$ if and only if $a-b \equiv \pm 1$, $\pm 2$, $\pm 3$, or $N/2 \pmod{N}$.

@ThomasAndrews, I do not require connected. And this task is given in the following way: write all possibilities, so I guess there are not many of them

@RobertIsrael, for 8 - yes. Do not know about other possibilities yet

For $N=10$, take $K_{10}$ and remove a $10$-cycle of edges.  For $N=12$, two $12$-cycles with no edges in common,

@ThomasAndrews, how did you get every even number $\ge 36$?

The Frobenius coin problem with counts of value $4$ and $7$ says that all numbers $\geq 18$ can be represented as $4a+7b$ for $a,b\geq 0$ integers. Then any even $N\geq 36$ can be written as $8a+14b,$ and since we have examples for $8$ and $14,$ that means we can get an example for any even $N\geq 36.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

@ThomasAndrews, that's great! But it seems too difficult... I expected this graph question to be easier. Now we also need to check each even number from 16 to 34, right?

Yeah, it was the first thing I thought of, is all. There was already a comment that answered the question fully.

@DanielSchepler, could you please give me some intuition? How did you come up with this solution?

If non-simple graphs are allowed:

 

